# Looking for assistance in getting proper results from .filter()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter an array with a string that is input by user. The results are not updating properly with the first key input, then if the box is cleared or characters removed/changed, results that may now pass the filter are not being displayed.

The goal is to have all results displayed on initial page render, then properly updated with each keystroke.

Apologies; I'm just learning to code. Thanks for all assistance.

```
searchCompUsers = () => {
    const newState = {}
            const filteredEmps = this.props.employees.filter(
                user => user.name.includes(this.state.searchName)
            )
            console.log(filteredEmps)
   ``         newState.filterEmps = filteredEmps
            this.setState(newState)
}

empSearch = evt => {
    const stateToChange = {};
    stateToChange[evt.target.id] = evt.target.value;
    this.setState(stateToChange);
    this.searchCompUsers()
};
```

Comment: is your `console.log(filteredEmps)` working as you type?

Comment: Yes; however, on the first keyUp, the filter is evidently not working properly, as results that should not pass the filter are being logged. On the subsequent keyUps, the filter is working properly, until I delete characters. It's as though once something is filtered out, it cannot be added back to the filteredEmps array.

Answer (score 0):

These lines are being run in sequence:

```
this.setState(stateToChange);
this.searchCompUsers();

...
const filteredEmps = this.props.employees.filter(
    user => user.name.includes(this.state.searchName)
)
...
this.setState(newState);
```

I am assuming in your example, `evt.target.id` is `searchName`.

Two things you're doing here which you shouldn't do:

1. Running two `setState`s in sequence.  This isn't necessarily a problem, but there's generally no reason for it and it could mean your code is structured poorly.
2. Referencing the state immediately after `setState`.  **`setState` is run asynchronously**, so you can't guarantee the state will be updated by the time you reach your filter.

The weird results you're getting are probably stemming from (2).

Something like this would work better, assuming the rest of your code is fine:

```
empSearch = evt => {
    const key = evt.target.id;
    const value = evt.target.value;
    if (key === "searchName") {
       const filteredEmps = this.props.employees.filter(
           user => user.name.includes(value);
       );
       this.setState({
           filterEmps: filteredEmps
       });
    }
};
```

This way, you're only calling `setState` once per event, and you're not relying on the results of an earlier `setState`.

If you need to keep `searchName` in the state for some reason (such as using a controlled component), then you can simply add it to the same `setState`.

```
   this.setState({
       filterEmps: filteredEmps,
       searchName: value
   });
```

The only places you can assume the state is up-to-date is in the `render()` function, and in certain React lifecycle functions.  You can also provide a callback to `setState` if necessary, though this should be relatively rare: `this.setState({ ...someState }, () => { ...someCodeToRun() });`

Comment: So, I was able to mak e the filtering work when the searchName field is updated, even when characters are removed and maybe a new string is inserted. The problem I'm having now is no cards are being rendered when the component mounts. I have tried: `componentDidMount() {
        const newState = {}
        newState.filterEmps = this.props.employees
        this.setState(newState)
    }` but the state of the component does not update. Thoughts?

Comment: @CharlesBelcher How are the props being provided through the parent?  Is the parent's version of `employees` being populated in its `componentDidMount`?  Be aware that the child's `componentDidMount` is always run before the parent's `componentDidMount`, and is only run once.  If so, you'll want to consider methods which handle incoming props changing, such as calculating the filter on render, and just keeping the search string in the component state.

Comment: In my personal opinion, I wouldn't keep the filtered list in your state at all, keeping only the search string in your state, and filter `this.props.employees` in your render function.  This could be marginally less performant, but is far FAR more flexible when it comes to react.  If you for some reason MUST keep the filtered list in the state, consider looking at `getDerivedStateFromProps` and `componentDidUpdate`.